# Double registration form in moodle

Tags: forms, registration, moodle

I'm editing a site based on moodle, and i need to create a double registration form. The first is already set (for schools), i need to create another one for private user. What would be the best way to do it?
Would be worth to copy the main signup files (signup.php and signup_form.php) and then make changes there?
Really thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to create a new authentication plugin.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins

Maybe copy the code from here `/auth/email` into `/auth/newname` - replacing email with newname in the code.

Possibly extend the class? so something like this in `/auth/newname/auth.php`

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/auth/email/auth.php');

class auth_plugin_newname extends auth_plugin_email {

    ...

    function can_signup() {
        return true;
    }

    ...
```

Then copy `/login/signup_form.php` into `/auth/newname/signup_form.php`

The next bit I'm not too sure about but you will probably need to modify `/login/signup.php`

Around the lines

```
if (empty($CFG->registerauth)) {
    print_error('notlocalisederrormessage', 'error', '', 'Sorry, you may not use this page.');
}
$authplugin = get_auth_plugin($CFG->registerauth);
```

Change to

```
if (optional_param('newname', false, PARAM_BOOL)) {
    $authplugin = get_auth_plugin('newname');
} else {
    if (empty($CFG->registerauth)) {
        print_error('notlocalisederrormessage', 'error', '', 'Sorry, you may not use this page.');
    }
    $authplugin = get_auth_plugin($CFG->registerauth);
}
```

Then for private registrations use

http://www.yoursite.com/login/signup.php?newname=1

Replace 'newname' with the name of your new authentication plugin.

Comment: Ok it works, but i need to change fields with the private user signup, i think i have to copy even signup.php and modify some code there. I'm gonna try and let you know, really thanks !

Comment: oh if you extended `auth_plugin_email`, then copy and modify `function user_signup` from `/auth/email/auth.php`

Comment: Ok really thanks. Now, i doubled the form and created new form elements via addElement() function. How can i retrieve the values of those elements and store them in a specific database table? Maybe something with $form -> get_data()? Really thanks, i'm new to moodle developing and i'm trying to understand the structure...

Comment: yes, use $data = $form->get_data() then you can use $data->fieldname

Comment: Really thanks. One last question, in which function do you think i have to write the $data value and the database insert?

Comment: Keep this page open while developing in Moodle - it's a useful reference for the database functions, the one you need is `insert_record('tablename', $newdata)` - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Inserting_Records

Comment: My problem is this :
1) I extend the class moodle_form and create new form field written in the function definition();
2) Then, when i write $mform->get_data() in this function, the form doesn't display anymore...i'm really new to object programming, if i try to var_dump the object i get a blank screen...
Can you help me in any way? Thank you so much..

Comment: does the $form->get_data() goes in function definition()?

Comment: ok, i have to use get_data in the validation function because it returns an empty object until the data is validated